# Strange Twitter Bootstrap Behaviour

Tags: php, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have been using the Twitter Bootstrap to put together a PHP website and I have encountered some odd behaviours that I cannot fix. I use a loop to create image boxes (There is a screenshot below) but for some reason the loop creates really weird alignment issues (I am trying to get them in vertical columns). All code is below. If anyone can help or point me in the right direction that would be awesome.

```
 foreach ($media->data as $data) {
        $x = $instagram->likeMedia($data->id);
        $usr = $data->caption->from->username;
        echo "<div class=\"span2\">";
        echo "<span style=\"text-align: center;\">";
        echo "<a href=\"{$data->link}\" target=\"_blank\">";
        echo "<div class=\"well\">";
        echo "<img src=\"{$data->images->thumbnail->url}\" alt=\"Loading...\">";
        echo "</a><br /><br /><a rel=\"tooltip\" title=\"Visit {$usr}'s Profile\" class=\"btn btn-primary btn-small\" href=\"http://instagram.com/{$usr}\">View Profile</a><br /></span>";
        echo "</div></div>";
        }
```

HTML code in browser window: http://snippi.com/s/dagwl09

Screenshot of strange behaviour in browser:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Jsfiddle :[Demo with images](http://jsfiddle.net/shail/TnJ8R/1/show/)

The issue is that you have created a single row and implemented all the span columns inside it . The grid can only 12 cols and you have inserted 18 so they wont align that way . 
Also rightly mentioned by other user that the closing tags are closing in wrong way .

Your row column should look like this :

```
 <div class="span2">
<span style="text-align: center;"><a href="http://instagr.am/p/WQok38nelp/" target="_blank">
    <div class="well">
        <img src="http://distilleryimage1.s3.amazonaws.com/8b0f6290815811e2b55e22000a9f09fb_5.jpg" alt="Loading..."></a><br /><br /><a rel="tooltip" title="Visit youtayloratsix's Profile" class="btn btn-primary btn-small" href="http://instagram.com/youtayloratsix">View Profile</a><br/>
    </div>
 </span>
 </div>
```

You can arrange your images in the following way

```
<div class="row-fluid">
   <div class="span2"></div>
   <div class="span2"></div>
   <div class="span2"></div>
   <div class="span2"></div>
   <div class="span2"></div>
   <div class="span2"></div>
 </div>
 <div class="row-fluid">
   <div class="span2"></div>
   <div class="span2"></div>
   <div class="span2"></div>
   <div class="span2"></div>
   <div class="span2"></div>
   <div class="span2"></div>
```

Place the images in the span2 and everything should work as intended.

Comment: You are welcome buddy ! Created a jsfiddle for you as well .. cleaned up some code ..

Comment: Hi, sorry to bother you again, but I have another question. At the moment I am using a `foreach` loop to echo the images. How would I insert a `<div class="row-fluid">` and `</div>` every six images?

Comment: you can use nested divs to achieve it.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are having the divs and spans opening/closing in the wrong order, could be an issue. Its at least invalid html.

You are opening them in order `<div>,<span>,<div>`, but closing in `</span>,</div>,</div>`.

Comment: Tried that just now, still having the same problem :)

Comment: I would assume that the issue is then inside the css/html code.

Comment: Yeap. I have a version that works with a previous version of my website and that code is at http://snippi.com/s/pzqw242 but even after copying and pasting it into the new version it does not work. That suggests it is a CSS problem I think.